# Website template Fluid or Responsive?

Tags: html, fluid

Okay I am a bit confused here, I have recently started making templates for sale, and now usually responsive templates.

So I was making a new design that had a basic css of the following design:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 700px;
}

.main {
   width: 66%;
   float: left;
}

.side {
   width: 33%;
   float: right;
}
```

Okay so this is a basic code that shows that my template is a fluid template.
And when the browser resizes it gives the responsive effect, though we all know that it is not a responsive template.

My issue here is such, that I have used some css codes to relocate content when the browser is resized. meaning that the website is now responsive too.

First of all I do not know if this is allowed as a valid website? Do I need to change the width 100% to specific widths or there is no such rule?

Second, what would I call this type of website? Since I would be selling it on ThemeForest. I don't think there is such a website that can be called both Fluid Responsive Web Template. Or is there?

And last, not always, but there are times, when I notice that the browser overflows on x axis. The content in the .side never stays in limits of 33%. Does anyone know why this might be the issue? Ill try to make out an example for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

better to use bootstrap 
It got everything for responsive design...
To Download it .. Please here is the link 
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I came across bootstrap after the template was made.
I shall check that out too.

Thanks.